How to list history of firmware update attempts?
I have a 3rd-gen Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 22.04.  It has UEFI/BIOS version N14ET25W (1.03) from 2014-12-01 and ME Firmware Version 10.0.29.1000.
On two separate dates, a few months apart, I've had errors when powering on: "Me FW Downgrade - Request MeSpiLock Failed".
The first day it happened, it occurred a few times in a row - I had to power off/on the laptop a few times before it would boot normally.  But both times it eventually resolved.
My research shows this error is normally associated with a failed UEFI/BIOS firmware update.  But I have never made any attempt to update my firmware on this device.
Ubuntu has a service called "fwupd" that can try to keep your firmware up-to-date.  But when I run this command, it shows no attempts to update my firmware by fwupd:
$ fwupdmgr get-history
WARNING: UEFI capsule updates not available or enabled in firmware setup
See https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:capsules-unsupported for more information.
No history

Running fwupdmgr get-devices just shows my SSD.
fwupd version:
$ wupdmgr --version
runtime   org. freedesktop. fwupd      1.7.9
runtime   com. dell. libsmbios         2.4
compile   org. freedesktop.gusb        0.3.10
compile   com. hughsie. libjcat        0.1.9
runtime   org. kernel                  6.8.0-47-generic
compile   org. freedesktop. fwupd      1.7.9
runtime   org. freedesktop.gusb        0.3.10

Could fwupd be responsible for my boot error by attempting to automatically upgrade my firmware? If so, is there some way I can confirm this from syslog or some other log?
If not fwupd, is there any other service in Ubuntu that might have attempted a firmware update, and how would I check?
Whilst the laptop seems to be working normally, I'm concerned about whether it's been subject to some kind of malware/firmware attack and whether I can trust this device.

You need a Lenovo or an FWUPD expert. https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo/issues/199 has some useful commands There is a claim it was fixed by doing a reinstall using a windows boot using an externl ssd.

Thanks for this.  My concern is more around understanding what was trying to update my firmware to cause the errors.  If I can't find any attempt by a legitimate service like fwupd to have performed this update, then I have to conclude it may have been an illegitimate update attempt.  Firmware based malware is supposed to be rare but definitely becoming more common.
